# 18.04 Lubuntu: How to check HDMI version?

Tags: hdmi, hardware

I'm on Lubuntu 18.04, is there any command that will list what version of HDMI my computer has? I have a Lenovo G767, hardly any info on it online. I need to ensure it has HDMI 1.4 because that is the bare minimum for running a 4k display on.

Comment: Suggest you find the serial number. On the same label there should be a model part number. That will help us look for details on the PC. Please click [edit] and paste it into the question when you find it, do not use Add Comment.  Don't find it? Go to https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/lenovo-g-series-laptops/lenovo-g700-notebook?linkTrack=Caps%3ABody_BrowseProduct&searchType=0&keyWordSearch= and enter your serial number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can **determine** the **date of manufacture** or **first customer boot date**, you can **compare** it to the **release dates of HDMI** versions and get a good idea as to which standard would have been applied.

```
$ sudo dmidecode | grep -A7 -i "oem strings"
OEM Strings
    String 1: AAABAAAAAWAA
    String 2: 2013/04/24
    String 3: SECPARTN:ABI
    String 4: Not Specified
    String 5: Not Specified
    String 6: Not Specified
    String 7: [LCD_15][IBT_00]
```

**Note**: These are free-form strings defined by the OEM. Manufacturers will configure them differently, so a date may or may not be there.
For reference, the System Management BIOS (SMBIOS) Reference Specification can be found [here](https://www.dmtf.org/sites/default/files/standards/documents/DSP0134_3.4.0a.pdf).

In my example, you can see the date given is: **2013/04/24**, which was the date I bought the computer, and the first time it was booted by a customer.

**Comparing** that to the **HDMI release dates** ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI)):
HDMI 2.0 was released on September 4, 2013
**HDMI 1.4b** was released on **October 11, 2011**
HDMI 1.4a was released on March 4, 2010
HDMI 1.4 was released on June 5, 2009
HDMI 1.3a was released on November 10, 2006
HDMI 1.3 was released on June 22, 2006
HDMI 1.2 was released on August 8, 2005
HDMI 1.1 was released on May 20, 2004
HDMI 1.0 was released on December 9, 2002

I can therefore **assume** my system is running **HDMI 1.4**, most probably **1.4b**